# map network drives

Tags: macos, applescript, user-account, mount, active-directory

I need to get a script that would map network drives based on a person's user name (we use AD to allow access). It used to work prior to 10.10.

We have a new Mac lab that is running 10.12.6. The old script is below.

I've installed *jq* from home-brew , but keep getting an error when I try to run it. (Also below)

Sorry I have no experience with AppleScript, and totally lost.

Any help would be appreciated

```
# Get Username and Tag Number.  Define the URL for the json request.

set user to do shell script "whoami"
set tag to do shell script "hostname -s"
set link to "https://my.gprc.ab.ca/AppService/api/NetworkMappings?UserName=" & user & "&ComputerName=" & tag
# Get the number of disks currently mounted.

set diskLength to length of (list disks)

# Get number of records in the json object.
# Define the first record number in the object.

set recordLength to do shell script "curl " & quoted form of link & " | jq 'length'"
set recordNumber to 0

# For each json record, determine if the object is a drive or printer and mount/install accordingly.

repeat recordLength times

    # Define a variable pointing to the first record returned by list disks.
    # set diskItem to 1

    try
        set networkPathVar to do shell script "curl " & quoted form of link & " | jq '.[" & recordNumber & "] | .NetworkPath' | cut -c 2- | sed 's:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\://:g' | sed 's:\\\\\\\\:/:g'  | sed 's:.$::'"
        set deviceType to do shell script "curl " & quoted form of link & " | jq '.[" & recordNumber & "] | .Type'"
    on error
        return
    end try


    if deviceType contains "Drive" then

        set recordNumber to recordNumber + 1

        # Check to see if the drive is already mounted.  If not mount it.

        # repeat diskLength times
        if networkPathVar does not contain items 1 thru diskLength of (list disks) then

            mount volume "smb:" & networkPathVar

        end if
        # end repeat

    else

        set recordNumber to recordNumber + 1
    end if # End of Device Type IF
end repeat
```

and the error I get is?

```
sh: jq: command not found
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    36  100    36    0     0    495      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   500
(23) Failed writing body

sh: jq: command not found
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    36  100    36    0     0    495      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   500
(23) Failed writing body (127)
```

Comment: The `PATH` passed to a `do shell script` _command_ is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, and any executable called that is not within that 'PATH` the _fully qualified pathname_ needs to be used. Also, I can't test your _code_, but the _output_ that's passed to `| cut -c 2- | sed 's:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\://:g' | sed 's:\\\\\\\\:/:g'  | sed 's:.$::'` could probably be replaced with a single `awk` command or at the lease the three piped `sed` _commands_ could be written as a single `sed` _command_ using `-e command` and not have to pipe to two additional occurrences of `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed `jq` in `/usr/local/bin` (or any other directory outside of `/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`). Usually this directory is not part of `PATH` so you need to specify the full path to run it (`/usr/local/bin/jq`).

Comment: sorry your are talking to someone that is sooooooo new to applyscript

Comment: We all have been there. Which part of the answer do I need to explain better?

Comment: @SteveLunney Simply replace the three occurrences of jq in the AppleScript with /usr/local/bin/jq and it should work. Tested - as far as  I can get without proper account at gprc.ab.ca.

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue being pointed out is not really an **AppleScript** issue per se. In other words, while the `do shell script` *command* is an **AppleScript** *command*, nonetheless, the issue is that the *command(s)* called by the `do shell script` *command* are not **AppleScript** *commands*, they are `shell` *commands* and as such are subject to the *environment* passed to the `shell` when the 
 `do shell script` *command* is executed.

The `PATH` passed to a `do shell script` *command* is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, and any executable called that is not within that `PATH`, then the *fully qualified pathname* needs to be used.

The `PATH` *environment variable* is a *colon-delimited* list of *directories* that your *shell* searches through when you enter a *command*.

Apparently `jq` is not within that `PATH`. In other words, `jq` is not located in one of the following locations: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

So, your choices are either *symlink* or *move* `jq` to one of those locations, or use the *fully qualified pathname* of the `jq` executable in the `jq` *command* within the *commands* of the `do shell script` *command*.

In the `do shell script` *command*, change `jq` to `/path/to/jq`

Example: `/usr/local/bin/jq`

Substitute `/usr/local/bin/` with the actual `/path/to/` the `jq` executable.

You might be able to ascertain its *path* in **Terminal** using the following *command*:

```
which jq
```

On my system the result of `which jq` is: `/usr/local/bin/jq`

If that doesn't work, then use the following *command* in **Terminal**:

```
find / -iname jq 2>/dev/null
```

So, you really do not need to understand **AppleScript** because the issue is a `shell` issue. Understanding how *shells* work is where you need to focus on your lack of understanding.